# Laravel login redirect doesn't work

Tags: laravel

I have made the login/tregistration form. Registration works well but login redirect doesn't work. I have the following function in my controller:

```
public function doLogin() {
    $credentials = [
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    } else {
        dd('error');
    }
}
```

and the routes.php

```
Route::resource('car', 'CarController');
Route::get('users', 'UserController@index');
Route::post('users/register', array('uses' => 'UserController@store'));
Route::post('users/signin', array('uses' => 'UserController@doLogin'));
Route::get('users/logout', array('uses' => 'UserController@doLogout'));
Route::get('/', 'CarController@index');
```

CarController

```
 public function index() {
        $cars = DB::select('select * from cars');
        $result = DB::select('select c.*, i.sgs, i.tpl, i.kasko, i.inter_permis from cars as c left join insur_docs as i  on i.car_id = c.id');
        $date = Carbon::now();
        $limit_date = Carbon::now()->addMonths(1);
        return View::make('pages.index', array(
                    'cars' => $cars,
                    'result' => $result,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'limit_date' => $limit_date,
        ));
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't redirects to index page just refresh the page. If not correct credentials it shows "error" else if correct credentials it just refresh page and doesn't redirects. I f I replace redirect with success message it shows it. I have the same code localy and login with redirect is ok, but in google app engine (my project online) doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 1):

The example you have used wouldn't actually redirect the user for two reasons.

1. The use of `Redirect::route()` excepts the parameter passed to be the name of a route, eg one defined like so

   `Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'YourController@yourMethod']);`

   To redirect here you would use `Redirect::route('home')`.
2. You aren't actually returning the redirect. Any response for a route, whether it be within a controller method or a closure, must be returned using the `return` keyword.

So to correct your code, it'd be like this:

```
public function doLogin() {
    $credentials = [
        'email' => Input::get('email'), 
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    } else {
        dd('error');
    }
}
```

I moved the credentials to an array as it looks tidier and it makes it easier to read when displaying on this site, so you don't have to do that, but it may make things easier for you.

Comment: sorry I put the wrong code in my question. My code is exactly like yours and it still does the same. Why localy it is working and online not?

Comment: You're using `return`? Does it redirect you but you end up on the login page?

Comment: yes that's the problem, it redirects me and ends in login page. What's the problem?

Comment: Make use of the `auth` route filter, to protect routes. Sounds to me like a user isn't actually being logged in. Is this a new installation? are the subdirectories in `app/storage` writable?

Comment: in filters.php Route::filter('auth', function()
{
 if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('users');
});
howto make app/storage writable? I have performed composer update . is this the problem?

Comment: Do you have command line access on the server? Does the user actually exist in the database? What's the code in `CarController@index`?

Comment: the user exists in db. because if i replace redirect with success message it displays it. I run commands from cmd. I used this CACLS  -R 755 app/storage to make my files writable, but this doesn't work in this case. I will add my code in controller index in my question. pls take a look

Comment: You're running this on a windows server?

Comment: You're using windows 8 for the remote server?

Comment: any idea about the problem?

Comment: I've never used google app engine, but my understanding is that it doesn't let you write to the disc. If that's the case, then sessions, nor logging would work.

Comment: I just removed the login to test it. And without login it displays the data from database(index page) which means that it is writable. What could be other problem with sessions?

Comment: That doesn't mean it's writable at all. That means that it can output, writable disc, writable database and output text are all different things.

Comment: how to test if is writable then?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem. It's definitely sessions related, but it sounds like an issue to do with google app engine more than anything.

Comment: as long as registration works. it should be writable? because stores data in db??

Comment: the same problem as http://laravel.io/forum/03-07-2014-laravel-authentication-issues  but don't know which is the solution

Comment: Database writes and disc writes are different. Unless of course they're both on the same machine, but even than there are ways to allow one but not the other.